# Effects of discretisation on bandwidth of low-pass filter

Tags: filter, signal-processing, digital-communications, low-pass, digital-filter

Consider a first order low-pass filter, with a cut-off frequency of (2π)*(8000). This filter will have a cut-off frequency at (2π)(8000), as well as a pole there.
$$
H(s) = \frac{1}{(\tau.s + 1)}
$$

When I discretise the system, with a sampling frequency of 20 kHz, using the Tustin transform, the frequency associated with the pole in the z-domain pole zero map seems to be different to that of the s-domain pole zero map. Below is a plot from MATLAB (continuous time filter on left, discrete time filter on left):

[image: Left: pzmap of continuous filter, Right: pzmap of discretised filter]

I just wanted to ask, why are these frequencies different? What is the relationship between the bandwidth of a continuous filter, and that of a discretised filter? How can I ensure that my discrete filter has the cut-off frequency I intended in my continuous time design?

What effects does discretisation have on the poles and zeros of my system, and it's dynamical characteristic more broadly?